# Captcha Built-In CSS Issue

Tags: css

The recaptcha i'm using have a built-in css of

```css
#recaptcha_area, #recaptcha_table {
  width: 318px !important;
}
```

I see this when I use firebug.

My problem is
how can I override the built-in width? I've tried to place css code on my stylesheet like

```css
#recaptcha_area, #recaptcha_table { 
  width: 207px !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is there other way to override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using `!important` to override things.

You can't tell the recaptcha what it's width should be; however, you can specify a maximum width instead:

```css
#recaptcha_area, #recaptcha_table { 
  max-width: 207px;
}
```

Note thought this might break the recaptcha area.

Comment: thanks, It works.. :) yes, I have look that one. But the recaptcha area is okay.. thanks again..

Comment: @justin: It does work, inspect `<div id="recaptcha_area">` and see how it's metrics width is set lower; however, it seems that you need to override every child that sets a wider width. Perhaps you can manipulate the `overflow` CSS attribute to resolve that?

Comment: @justin: Not sure but maybe one of it's values might do what you want, otherwise just inspect down the tree which things have a width > 207px and lock them using `max-width` or in the worst case `!important`.